# How to render custom data in Bootstrap-Vue Table component?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am using **Bootstrap-Vue** and **VueJs** and need help with some custom data rendering from multiple data objects and displaying the data into a table. Specifically, I am following this part of the Bootstrap-Vue TABLE docs: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/table#formatter-callback but I am unsure how to apply it to my code.

*Here's my scenario:*

I have a data API providing 2 different arrays of objects: `posts` and `names`

> Posts:

```
    [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
...snip..
    ]
```

> and Names:

```
[{"userId":1,"first_name":"Neill","last_name":"Dexter","email":"ndexter0@thetimes.co.uk"},
...snip
]
```

The **`posts`** array contains a `userId` key but no name of the user. The **`names`** array contains the `userId` key and the `first_name` and `last_name` of that user.

**What I want to do is simply display the full name of the user in my Bootstrap-vue Table component rather than the `userId` because just showing the userId doesn't make sense.**

Here's my attempt ([**link to editable live code**](https://codesandbox.io/embed/loading-issue-h17lp)):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table :items="posts" :fields="fields">
      <!-- A custom formatted column -->
      <template slot="name" slot-scope="data">{{ data.value.userId }}</template>
    </b-table>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      names: [],
      // key name is the slot name
      fields: [
        { key: "id" },
        { key: "title" },
        { key: "body" },
        { key: "name", label: "Assigned To", formatter: "assignNames" }
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getPosts();
    this.getNames();
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").then(resp => {
        this.posts = resp.data;
      });
    },
    getNames() {
      axios
        .get("https://my.api.mockaroo.com/users.json?key=f119e0f0")
        .then(resp => {
          this.names = resp.data;
        });
    },
    assignNames() {
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < this.posts.length; i++) {
        if (this.posts[i].userId !== null) {
          const result = this.names.filter(name => {
            return name.userId === this.posts[i].userId;
          });
          this.posts[i].userId =
            result[0].first_name + " " + result[0].last_name;
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Anyone got any tips on how I can show the full name of my users rather than just the userId? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
assignNames(id) {
  const user = this.names.find(e => e.userId === id);
  return  user ? `${user.first_name} ${user.last_name}` : 'loading...';
}
```

... but, obviously, the key has to be `userId`, as that's the name of the property referenced in `post` structure:

```
{ key: "userId", label: "Assigned To", formatter: "assignNames" }
```

See it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/loading-issue-fntfm).

Also, you shouldn't name the results from second api `names`, but `users`.

---

**Note:** In the example I linked I placed the results of `users` inside a json saved in the project and mocked the api call by a promise getting that json, as your api key exceeded its daily limit and was returning a `500`.

Comment: Unfortunately, your users API exceeded its daily limit and returns `500` now. You might want to make a new account, grab the dummy data, save it as json in your project and mock an http request to it. Note the way you're currently handling fetching data, any change in the editor will cause the app to rebuild and refetch.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will study this. Quick question...is the `find()` method safe to use in browsers? I saw it's not compatible with IE11 and earlier.

Comment: To use it in IE you'd need its [polyfill](https://github.com/jsPolyfill/Array.prototype.find). Or [this one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) (they might actually be the exact same thing).

Comment: If I use vue-cli does it come with the polyfill?

Comment: Took me a while, but I got it working with my actual data. Thank you! P.S> I noticed that the table doesn't filter the custom formatter data...I'll have to look into that.

Comment: No, `vue-cli` doesn't include any polyfill, afaik. Probably the simplest way to load needed polyfills is to use them [as a service](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/an-easier-way-of-using-polyfills/). From [here](https://cdn.polyfill.io/v3/api/).

Comment: And, btw, currently IE has a market share of 2.58%. I'd say about half of that is website owners and developers testing if their website works in it. And which is a smaller share than what Samsung Internet and UC Browser have, each.